# Change grails linked resources path in GGTS

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.3.2 with GGTS and am doing development on two different machines (Mac and Windows). Each time I commit my project from one machine and update the other I have to refresh my dependencies. Is there a way I can set this to some sort of relative path? That way it doesn't have to change each time I do an update from my repository.

It seems that a full path is being included in my `.project` file as shown below.

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>.link_to_grails_plugins</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <location>C:/Users/michael/workspace/myproject/target/work/plugins</location>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

I changed it manually in the file, but GGTS seemed to change it back when I did the refresh. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some looking around it looks like I can specify a path relative to my workspace using the `WORKSPACE_LOC` and building up a path relative to that within my `.project` file.

```
<linkedResources>
  <link>
    <name>.link_to_grails_plugins</name>
    <type>2</type>
    <location>WORKSPACE_LOC/myproject/target/work/plugins
    </location>
  </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better is to not commit files generated by the GGTS and that are S.O. dependent.

If you're using git, there's a command to generate the file:

```
grails integrate-with --eclipse
```

If not, you can see the git file and ignore those files in the SVN.